# Making a music device from RPi

Tags: gpio, pi-zero, node.js

I am making a musical instrument from a raspberry pi out of cardboard. It would be like a piano with an octave of notes (13 including sharps). How would I get the raspberry pi to detect when a circuit is made. Would I use the GPIO? Is there enough, as I also want to add a few LEDs, for information like wifi connection (it would be running headless), and modular keys, like one to trigger a drum sound. I don't know much about GPIO, like which pins I can use for input. I am writing the script in NodeJS, so I assume I would use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpi-gpio. Also, I intend for this to be a cheap device (hopefully under £30 GBP/$38 USD), so it would use the pi 0W.

Comment: see this .... https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-sensors-overview-50-important-components/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All modern Pi's with the 40-pin header (including the 0W) have 26 GPIO pins - more than enough for 13 switches and some LEDs. Each one can either be an input or an output.

For the keys, you could use some standard, run-of-the-mill tactile pushbuttons. You can find a tutorial on the concepts behind this [here](https://grantwinney-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/grantwinney.com/using-pullup-and-pulldown-resistors-on-the-raspberry-pi/amp/?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQECAFYAQ%3D%3D#referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fgrantwinney.com%2Fusing-pullup-and-pulldown-resistors-on-the-raspberry-pi%2F) (although it's for Python, not Node). Drum triggers would also be pretty simple; just hook up a mono jack in place of the pushbutton.

I'd recommend looking through some basic GPIO tutorials first for the Pi, to help you grasp how they work, such as [this one on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_raspberrypi_blinking_led.asp).

Comment: A couple parallel to serial shift registers could also greatly increase the amount of GPIO on there.  :-)